# Data after formatting a floppy disk

Tags: filesystems

I made a C program for school which allow me to write directly a message on a floppy disk sector in FAT. I manage to read this message corretly but the question asks me if I can read it after formatting it into EXT2.
So I would like to know if it is possible or not and why ?
I tested myself and I can't read the message but i don't know if it's good.
Thanks

Comment: you mean _any sector_ or _some specific sector_? and please define _formatting_. Do you mean the _fast_ or the _overwrite everything with zeros_ way of formatting?

Comment: In my program, it's in the 3rd sector. And I don't know if it's the fast or complete, I used the command mkfs.ext2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you made a `hexdump -C /dev/sdX` of your disk before and after your formatting?
It would be interesting to view the difference, I think.

Concerning your outcome so far, according to [this article](http://homepage.smc.edu/morgan_david/cs40/analyze-ext2.htm) on analyzing the ext2 filesystem, the data on your floppy would begin by 1024 bytes of zeros that make up the boot block. Then would follow the superimportant superblock.
Assuming a sectorsize of 512 bytes (I don't know how probable that is for your setting) your message was indeed overwritten by the ext2-superblock. Honorable end!